# Изменить значение глобальной переменной

Tags: python, telebot

Есть глобальная переменная "summ"в нее пользователь передает значение в штуках.  мне необходимо это значение умножить на цену.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == "zakaz")
def choise_service(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    time.sleep(3)
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Оплатить на сайте", url='https://,,,,,'),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Банковской картой", url='https://sberbank.ru')
        )
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id,
                              message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text="Для заказа  <b>" +summ+ " Мешков </b>  оплатите :\n➖➖➖➖\n<b>" +summ*228+ " рублей </b>\n на <b>Банковскую карту</b> " \
                "\n➖➖➖➖\n<code>45000000000000</code>\n➖➖➖➖\n ,
                              reply_markup=markup,parse_mode='HTML')
```

Comment: Создавал новую переменную
    global itog
    itog = summ*228

Comment: внутри функции пишете ```global summ``` и тогда сможете работать с переменной ```summ``` внутри функции

Comment: Пробовал так уже, а summ без определения в этой функциив первой строчке text="Для заказа  <b>" +summ+ " Мешков она выдает правильное значение которое пользователь ввел! весь день долблюсь(

Comment: Похоже, вы пытаетесь соединить строку и число. Там, где у вас ```text=``` вместо ```summ``` напишите ```str(summ)``` и вместо ```summ*228``` напишите ```str(summ*228)```

Comment: тоже не выходит